# How can two threads communicate while both are running?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I've been trying to teach myself concurrency, and I've run into an issue.  I understand that two Java threads can communicate to each other via `wait()` and `notify()`.  However, this requires one thread to be inactive and essentially "just sitting around" until the other one wakes it up.

Is it possible to have both threads running simultaneously and still have them listening for notifications from the other?  Would this be accomplished through concurrency techniques or instead something like an `ActionListener`?

For example, the project I'm testing this on is basically a grid where different entities wander around through different cells.  When two of the entities happen to wander into the same cell, I'd like one to notify the other and something different to happen based on this (for instance, a greeting: "Hello there!").  But as it stands, with the wait/notify paradigm, one of the threads/entities has to simply sit in one cell waiting for another to wander in; they can't both move around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few ways you can communicate between threads. Using the most common approach you can use instance variables to share info between threads but you must take care to only write from one thread or synchronize any updates to the shared variable. Alternatively you can use Piped I/O streams which were designed for inter-thread communication, or passing raw data between threads. One thread writes info to the stream while the other reads it.

Here's an example method that would read output from a slow network connection and dump it to System.out using threads.

```
    public void threads() throws IOException {
    final PipedOutputStream outputForMainThread = new PipedOutputStream();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(moreDataOnNetwork()) {
                byte[] data = readDataFromNetwork();
                try {
                    outputForMainThread.write(data);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new PipedInputStream(outputForMainThread)));
    for(String eachLine = reader.readLine(); eachLine != null; eachLine = reader.readLine()) {
        System.out.println(eachLine);
    }
}
```

However it almost sounds like you want an event callback mechanism where one thread (your user interface thread) is notified when the other thread detects a certain condition. Depending on your platform much of this is baked in. Using Android, for eg., you could have a thread that determines that a grid entity moved. It would send an update to the main user interface thread to repaint the screen. Such an update could resemble:

```
public void gridEntityDidUpdate(final Point fromLocation, final Point toLocation) {
    Activity activity = getMainActivity();
    activity.runOnUiThread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateScreen(fromLocation, toLocation);
                    if(pointsAreCoincedent(fromLocation, toLocation)) {
                        System.out.println("Hello there!");
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}

private void updateScreen(Point fromLocation, Point toLocation) {
    //Update the main activity screen here
}
```

In this scenario you have a background thread that works out the position of all on-screen elements and notifies the main thread when elements positions change. There is an extracted method that determines if 2 points are coincidental or the same.

Comment: Great answer!  However, my question is more like, how could I get two on-screen elements to communicate to one another, rather than having them communicate with the UI. :)  I'm also not using a GUI for this project, but I understand the point of your example.

Comment: maybe explain a little more about your current code. How many threads are you using and what is each thread responsible for? It sounds like you have 2 threads each controlling an individual on-screen element in which case you might get away with something quick/dirty like a Point member variable for each element. Before either thread performs an action it could check the member variable of the other thread and respond accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Erlang` **language** to communicated safely **among** the `Processes` which runs within there own Address space along with `Java` as a better and safe alternative to thread.

Answer (score 1):

> I've been trying to teach myself concurrency, and I've run into an issue. I understand that two Java threads can communicate to each other via wait() and notify().

The "classic" Java threading tutorials teach wait/notify early on.  Back around the Java 1.1, 1.2 time frame that's all there was.

However if you can get a copy of the excellent "Java Concurrency in Practice" by Brian Goetz, wait/notify are not discussed until chapter 14 "Building Custom Synchronizers" in section IV advanced topics.  I am severely paraphrasing here, but the impression I got was "OK if you've read the 300 previous pages and none of the building blocks discussed so far meet your needs, then you can try building your own using wait/notify".

My point is that wait/notify, although very important, might not be the best place to start learning concurrency.  Some of the answers/comments in this question (producer/consumer, ExecutorService) are referring to the higher level concurrency building blocks that were added in Java 5.  Even though this stuff was added later, it's the stuff you should be learning first.

Back to your question - here are a couple of thoughts:

If this is a GUI application and you want to have a background thread do some work, check out [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).  I have had success using a SwingWorker (section 9.3.3) where the background thread reads messages from a blocking queue (section 5.3) does some work and notifies the GUI thread by invoking the higher level "publish" method.  No "wait/notify" - at least not in my code.

If the application is not Swing-based and you want to have different threads performing tasks in parallel and occasionally send messages to each other, consider [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org) "The socket library that acts as a concurrency framework."  With ZeroMQ, each thread is running an event loop which reads and processes messages.  A thread can schedule work on it's own thread by sending itself a message.  It can schedule work/notify a different thread by sending a message to that thread (socket).

Anyhow, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ThreadManager` class, which has `List<Thread>` and is kind of like a semaphore object.  Your threads should be able to find and reference other threads from there.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have both threads running simultaneously and still have them listening for notifications from the other?

Whenever they are not waiting, they can be doing something at the same time.  If they appear to be just waiting for each other it is likely you are better off with one thread. (Using multiple threads is not always better)

> Would this be accomplished through concurrency techniques or instead something like an ActionListener?

It is more likely to be a design issue with how you have broken down the problem.  Threads work best when there is a minimum of interaction between them.  If they are highly dependent on each other you should consider using less threads.

> But as it stands, with the wait/notify paradigm, one of the threads/entities has to simply sit in one cell waiting for another to wander in;

I don't see why you need wait/notify here at all. I would just have them move around and send messages to one another when they are in the same cell.

Comment: I understand that they can both be doing things if they aren't waiting.  The question is how to have them communicate *while* both are running.  Essentially, how to have them "send messages to one another" as you say, without one waiting on the other to do so.

Comment: Then you need a producer-consumer queue, I guess.  Many threads loop around P-C queue reads - very common design.  The inter-thread messages queue up until the consumer gets around to actioning them.

Comment: I would use an ExecutorService to have threads working together. You give the thread pool work and correct the results when you need them